# gimme-aws-creds fails on cmd during registration of device

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, aws-cli, okta, gimme-aws-creds

I am using windows 10.
I installed python 3.11.1, pip 23.x and installed gimme-aws-creds 2.3.1. After that I executed gimme-aws-creds, it results in error.

> C:\Windows\System32>gimme-aws-creds
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\gimme-aws-creds.cmd", line 47, in
> GimmeAWSCreds().run()
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gimme_aws_creds\main.py", line 466, in run
> self._run()
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gimme_aws_creds\main.py", line 769, in _run
> self.handle_action_configure()
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gimme_aws_creds\main.py", line 798, in handle_action_configure
> if not self.config.action_configure:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gimme_aws_creds\main.py", line 489, in config
> self.resolver = self.get_resolver()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gimme_aws_creds\main.py", line 555, in get_resolver
> return AwsResolver(self.config.verify_ssl_certs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File ".......................\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gimme_aws_creds\aws.py", line 41, in init
> retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: Retry.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method_whitelist'

To resolve this I upgraded Python to 3.12 and gimme-aws-creds to 2.4.0. But I am getting the same issue.Because of this I am not able register to Okta MFA. Can you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved by replacing installed version of urllib3 with urllib3==1.25.11